# Is odd continuous function differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, parity

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous and odd: $f(-x) = - f(x)$.
Does it have a derivative at $x=0$?

Here is what I got so far: First we calculate $f(0)$ using $f(-0) = -f(0)$, from which $f(0) = 0$.
Then we calculate $f'(0)$ as follows:
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}
= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,.
$$
But the limit from the left is equal to the limit from the right:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)}{x}
=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(-x)}{-x}
=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-f(x)}{-x}
=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,,
$$
which means that as long as the limit from the right exists, the function is differentiable at $x=0$. The limit is of the type $\frac{0}{0}$, since both $x$ and $f(x)$ goes zero at $x=0$. However, since $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$, then in the vicinity of $x=0$, it must have a well defined value and the limit should exist. However, I didn't figure out how to finish the proof.

I've been trying to construct counter examples.
A simple example is $f(x) = x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}$, which is continuous (we define $f(0)=0$) and odd, with the derivative $f(x) = 2x\sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}$,
which oscillates between -1 and 1 around $x=0$. But at $x=0$, the derivative should be equal to zero, because $\frac{f(x)}{x} = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ which goes to zero. So the derivative does exist at $x=0$ here.

Comment: $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: N.S., you are right! $\frac{f(x)}{x} = \sin\frac{1}{x^2}$ which oscillates between -1 and 1 and so the limit does not exist. So this function is not differentiable at $x=0$. Thanks!

Comment: @N.S.: You should have converted your comment to an actual answer. It certainly deserves upvotes.

Comment: @N.S. Please do, I didn't want to put your solution into answers myself.

Comment: @OndřejČertík Done :)

Answer (score 8):

You can consider the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 3):

What you can say about 
$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sqrt{x}, & x>0, \\
 0,& x=0, \\
 -\sqrt{-x}, & x<0.
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

$$f(x)=x \sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$$